# Making code "CAS-safe" and "environment safe"

Tags: c#, .net

I read an article about making code reliable in different environments (what with CAS having an influence), and one technique was to use .GetExecutingAssembly(...) for accessing resources in an assembly (Eg text files). Is there any other useful technique?

I ask as some stuff I am writing will be demo'd from another machine.

Thanks

Comment: How about a link to the article?

Answer (score 0):

I think these two MSDN articles should provide you the information you need about accessing resources in an assembly:

[Resources in Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f45fce5x%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

[Packaging and Deploying Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb6a8618%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)